# Angular 4 "Property does not exist on type component"

Tags: angular, typescript

This last week I've started learning Angular 4 and TypeScript, and I've hit my first roadblock.

I'm trying to make a simple date and time component. From a Javascript view I can't see anything wrong, but I think I'm not working with scope the way Angular wants, so I'm looking for some guidance. The error is:
`Failed to compile very/long/file/path/date-time.component.ts (35,18): Property 'date' does not exist on type 'DateTimeComponent'.`

I suspect I'm not putting my methods in the right place, or I need to declare my properties outside of `setTime()`. Any advice much appreciated.

date-time.component.ts:

```
export class DateTimeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setTime();
  }

  checkTime(i) {
    return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
  }

  setTime() {

    let month = ["January", "February", 
    "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", 
    "July", "August", 
    "September", "October", 
    "November", "December"];

    //date
    let date: Date = new Date(); // this only accessible within setTime() method
    let d: any = date.getDate();
    let m: any = date.getMonth();
    let y: any = date.getFullYear();
    //time
    let h: any = date.getHours();
    let min: any = date.getMinutes();
    let s: any = date.getSeconds();

    let newMin: any = this.checkTime(this.min);
    let newS: any = this.checkTime(this.s);

    let myDate: any = d + " " + month[this.m] + " " + y;
    let myTime: any = h + ":" + newMin + ":" + newS; 

    let t: any = setTimeout(() => {
      startTime()
    }, 500);

  }

} //end of class
```

date-time.component.html:

```
<div ng-controller='TimeCtrl'>
  <p>{{ myDate }}</p>
  <p>{{ myTime }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you pay a little more attention to your code inside `ngOnInit`, you will see the problem

Comment: What @Dummy said. Also none of your variables are being declared. You're also trying to access those variables incorrectly (`eg. d = this.date.getDate()`). There's a lot wrong here.

Comment: @JunKang the tutorials I've seen declare some variables like `i = "thing"` and it works just fine. Adding `var` to mine seemingly makes no difference. Should I be declaring all variables outside of the methods, with set types? If so it seems rather overdone.

Comment: what tutorial are you looking at? there is so much wrong with this that i dont know where to start. for example, first of all, in your html, thats not how you use an angular component in angular2+. its how you would bind a controller to a div in angularjs(angular1). Also, you dont have to declare all variables outside the methods. but you do have to declare them, at least locally, if you want to use them. also, your functions `checkTime()` and `setTime()`  are being declared inside `ngInit()`, which it shouldnt be. It should be outside of the `ngInit()` within the scope of the component itself

Comment: @JunKang I've updated my code, hope it's an improvement. Really appreciate that info on how things should be structured.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SmMwb7J9qSIM7uFEPylj?p=preview) showing your thing working in an Angular environment. This isn't a good way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Instead, you should do something like this [better plunker that I made](https://plnkr.co/edit/cxWOmC8Zt2GcaSBDKZWG?p=preview) that actually uses Angular to its full potential.

My version of your code is like 99% shorter, and accomplishes the goal.

```
myDate: Date;

ngOnInit() {
  this.myDate = new Date();
}
```

With the HTML

```
<p>{{ myDate | date:'d MMMM y'}}</p>
<p>{{ myDate | date:'hh:mm:ss'}}</p>
```

Comment: I really like the efficiency here, but I really need to learn how to use methods, etc. I need to grasp the fundamentals of so many things and using code as clean as this would teach me little.

I think it would be best if I accept this as the answer as it works so well, and go study my brains out till I think I can build something once again. Hopefully when I come here for help next I'll have problems aside from code that is god awful.

Comment: The first plunker does work, and shows how your code should be formatted to work. So you can still go off that to learn a little bit of what you're doing. The reason your code wasn't working before was for a few reasons. 1. Your variables `myDate` and `myTime` need to be declared publicly within the scope of the component itself, so it can be referenced in the html. 2. When updating those variables in the function `setTime()`, you need to use `this.myDate` and `this.myTime` because that's how you access variables declared in the scope of the component inside your functions.

Comment: 3. Since you declared the function `checkTime()` in the scope of the component, you also call that function with `checkTime()` when calling it inside the function `setTime()`. 4. Yes, all the variables need to be declared within the function `setTime()` itself if you want to use them. Using `let` declares the variables within the scope of the block you're using it in, as opposed to `var` which declares it globally within the scope its being used in. Using `var` is fine. Using `let` is also fine, in this context.

Comment: 5. In your html, the div should not have the property `ng-controller` on it at all. That's how controllers are defined using AngularJS (Angular 1). Not Angular (Angular 2+ (currently on version 4)). 6. You don't NEED to define a variables type, like `myDate: Date` but it's good to when its not implicit. E.g. If you do `myDate = new Date()`, it's not necessary to define the variable as a Date, because it is implicitly a date. But in my version, I did `myDate: Date;` with `this.myDate = new Date();` in the `ngOnInit()` function because at the time that `myDate` was declared, it wasn't implicit.

Comment: btw in number 3, I said "you also call that function with `checkTime()`". That should be `this.checkTime()` because `checkTime()` is declared in the scope of the component.

Comment: What do you think of this? I am making a new Date object every half-second, I'm wondering if it's efficient. https://jsfiddle.net/nj7fmLvp/

Comment: How we can do with string and another data type like an array, Object

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have not `declared` the variable `date` on your component.

```js
export class DateTimeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 

  }
  
  private date: Date; // This is accessible to this entire file
  private month: string[];
  private d: any;
  private m: any;
  private y: any;
  private h: any;
  private min: any;
  private s: any;
  private newMin: any;
  private newS: any;
  private myDate: any;
  private myTime: any;
  private t: any;
  
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  
  checkTime(i) {
      return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    setTime() {
      this.month = ["January", "February", 
      "March", "April", 
      "May", "June", 
      "July", "August", 
      "September", "October", 
      "November", "December"];

      //date
      this.date = new Date();
      this.d = this.date.getDate();
      this.m = this.date.getMonth();
      this.y = this.date.getFullYear();
      //time
      this.h = this.date.getHours();
      this.min = this.date.getMinutes();
      this.s = this.date.getSeconds();

      this.newMin = this.checkTime(this.min);
      this.newS = this.checkTime(this.s);

      this.myDate = this.d + " " + this.month[this.m] + " " + this.y;
      this.myTime = this.h + ":" + this.newMin + ":" + this.newS; 

      this.t = setTimeout(() => {
        startTime()
      }, 500);
    }


} //end of class
```

```js
export class DateTimeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 

  }
 
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  checkTime(i) {
      return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    setTime() {
     let month = ["January", "February", 
      "March", "April", 
      "May", "June", 
      "July", "August", 
      "September", "October", 
      "November", "December"];

      //date
      let date: Date = new Date(); // this only accessible within setTime() method
      let d: any = date.getDate();
      let m: any = date.getMonth();
      let y: any = date.getFullYear();
      //time
      let h: any = date.getHours();
      let min: any = date.getMinutes();
      let s: any = date.getSeconds();

      let newMin: any = this.checkTime(this.min);
      let newS: any = this.checkTime(this.s);

      let myDate: any = d + " " + month[this.m] + " " + y;
      let myTime: any = h + ":" + newMin + ":" + newS; 

      let t: any = setTimeout(() => {
        startTime()
      }, 500);
    }

} //end of class
```

There two approaches to this, `snippet 1` show file wide declaration, this what you would mostly use in your app. The `Snippet 2` show `method` based declaration and its only accessible to that method, as far as files concerns, that variable doesn't exist.

> `private`

If you stick `private` in front of a `variable` or `method`, that will only be accessible to the `.ts` file (itself), not even the `HTML` has access to that.

Comment: as you know that `this.date` is going to be type Date, better if you use the type in the definition `private date: Date`

Comment: @nicowernli I was going to but wan't sure whether OP has relevant libraries  in the app, thats why left `any` I shall change it. Thanks

Comment: When `let date = new Date();` (Snippet 2) is used I get `Property 'date' does not exist`. Am I doing something else wrong? I can't think of how to make this object any more declared than it already is.

Comment: It might be because of this `this.date`. Word `this` reffers to a variable like on Snippet 1. It used to go up a level to the file level and look for the variable. If you remove it, it will use the one in the method

Comment: @Draxy Sorry it was my fault, I didn't pay attention other variables. I have made changes to both snippets, this should work. Don't forget to replace `any` with appropriate Types. I.E `string[]` (array of strings)

Comment: @PraveenM All this declaring and `Property 'min' does not exist` still, I'm starting to think I'm in over my head haha

Comment: Have you added `let` in front of the `min`? Assuming you're using the second snippet approach

Answer (score -1):

note that you are setting `date` try using `date.whatever` not `this.date.whatever`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'date-time',
  templateUrl: './date-time.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-time.component.css']
})
export class DateTimeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    checkTime(i) {
      return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    setTime() {
      month = ["January", "February", 
      "March", "April", 
      "May", "June", 
      "July", "August", 
      "September", "October", 
      "November", "December"];

      //date
      let date = new Date();
      d = date.getDate();
      m = date.getMonth();
      y = date.getFullYear();
      //time
      h = date.getHours();
      min = date.getMinutes();
      s = date.getSeconds();

      newMin = this.checkTime(this.min);
      newS = this.checkTime(this.s);

      myDate = this.d + " " + this.month[this.m] + " " + this.y;
      myTime = this.h + ":" + this.newMin + ":" + this.newS; 

      t = setTimeout(() => {
        startTime()
      }, 500);
    }

  }

} //end of class
```

that should work

Comment: By the way, you forgot to declare every other variable after `date`.